# Thumbnail doesnt show when i share an article on facebook from blogger

Tags: facebook, share, thumbnails

When i share an article from my blog to facebook, there is no image. only title.

My blog is on blogger.

Does anyone know how can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to explicitly mention the url of image through meta commands like

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://xyz/img.jpg"/>
```

check this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing
and http://ogp.me/